# メッシュの変形をスプリプトで行いたい

Tags: python, blender

Pythonスクリプトでモデルの変形を行いたいと考えています。

スカルプトモードで変形したものではログを見ることができなかったため、プロポーショナル編集の「球」で部分的に変形させています。

スクリプトは以下のようになっています。

```
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(4.95114, 0, 0), constraint_axis=(True, False, False), constraint_orientation='GLOBAL', mirror=False, proportional='ENABLED', proportional_edit_falloff='SPHERE', proportional_size=15.8631, release_confirm=True, use_accurate=False)
```

このスクリプトを実行すると選択した部分が球状に膨らむのではなく、元のモデル全体の位置が移動してしまいます。スクリプトに中心の点を指定する部分がないため当たり前のことが起こっているとは思うのですが、中心を指定したりその他の解決方法がわかりませんでした。

プロポーショナル編集をスクリプトで行うにはどのような方法があるのでしょうか。
もし他に同様にスクリプトで行える方法があればそちらも教えていただきたいです、よろしくお願いいたします。

[image: このようにプロポーショナル編集をしています]